# Grouping by id transpose the values negatiive and positive values using python

Tags: python, pandas

| id | Doct_id | date | description | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1021 | 355 | 14.02.2021 | doc_1 | -20 |
| 2010 | 355 | 14.02.2021 | doc_1 | 20 |
| 2010 | 358 | 20.05.2022 | doc_2 | 9 |
| 6120 | 358 | 20.05.2022 | doc_2 | -9 |
| 21201 | 358 | 20.05.2022 | doc_2 | 0 |

Expected output from above tabel using python

| id | Doct_id | date | description | amount | id_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1021 | 355 | 14.02.2021 | doc_1 | 20 | 2010 |
| 2010 | 358 | 20.05.2022 | doc_2 | 9 | 6120 |
| 21201 | 358 | 20.05.2022 | doc_2 | 0 | 6120 |

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, but if you want to find the matching negative value, see duplicate